# How to hide Forums from anonymous users?

Tags: 8, routes

I installed Forum module.
So, I have 'Forums' link in 'Tools' menu corresponding to the path /forum defined in `forum.routing.yml` in which access is defined by `_permission: 'access content'`.
In my site, anonymous users are allowed to "View published content", so they can see the 'Forum' link.
I don't want anonymous users to be able to see forums and, therefore, the forum topics.
I thought to override the _permission of `forum.routing.yml` but I don't know how to do that?
How can I do that?

Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the permission associated with a route doing what [Altering existing routes and adding new routes based on dynamic ones / Altering existing routes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones#s-altering-existing-routes) says to do.

- Create a service that is tagged with `name: event_subscriber`
- The class implementing the service extends [`RouteSubscriberBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21RouteSubscriberBase.php/class/RouteSubscriberBase/8.9.x)
- The service class defines its `alterRoutes()` method that in `RouteSubscriberBase` is an abstract method

In your case, the `alterRoutes()` method would be similar to the following one.

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('forum.index')) {
      $route->setRequirement('_permission', 'access forum pages');
    }
    if ($route = $collection->get('forum.page')) {
      $route->setRequirement('_permission', 'access forum pages');
    }
  }
```

Instead of *access forum pages*, you can use a different permission, including an existing one that you think it suits more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `role: authenticated user` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a solution to the same problem, I found this alternative:
https://www.drupal.org/project/group_forum
There is no documentation though.

The groups module documentation https://www.drupal.org/project/group/issues/2710909 says:

> Classes of a school website is a typical usecase of the Group module.
>
> With a teacher as the administrator, students as the members and the
> content as the learning material. Articles in the Group are created by
> the teacher and only visible to the students in the Group. Forums
> created in the Group are safe places to discuss the class as they are
> only accessible to the teacher and the students.

They are not working as private for me though.